# Meaning Go a long way

Tags: meaning

Would anyone like to explain me the meaning of phrase "GO A LONG WAY" and how can we use it in a sentence? 
And how can we use it as "WILL GO A LONG WAY " 
"GOES A LONG WAY"
"WENT A LONG WAY".

Comment: Good typography and minimal research *go a long way*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The phrase can have both literal and figurative meanings.

Literally, it means to travel a long distance.

> You will have to go a long way. The nearest hospital is 30 miles from here.

Figuratively, it means to go a significant "distance" towards a desired end:

> Apologizing will go a long way towards making things better between you.

Comment: It would be better to migrate this Q to ELL and answer it there. Answering it here, even a quality answer, sets a bad precedent, and distracts the site from its objectives.

Comment: I have no idea how to migrate a question. And whenever I choose "belongs on a different SE site" the only choice I see is "meta".

Comment: We can do it, you don’t need to do anything but forebear to answer ELL style questions on ELU.